# How can I identify the prototype typeof?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, types, prototypejs

I have 2 classes, base and child:

```
// base class
function circle(radius){
    this.radius = radius;
    return true;}

// child class
function pizza(flavour, radius){
    this.radius = radius;
    this.flavour = flavour;
    return true;}

// Inheritance
pizza.prototype = new circle();
```

Now I'm creating an instance of pizza:

```
var myPizza = new pizza("Onion", 5);
```

How can I now identify if this variable is `circle` or `pizza`?

I know I can add a function that will return me the name or hold property with the type name but I wondered if there is another way without changing any of my classes.

Thanks!

Comment: [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) ;)

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should probably call the `circle` constructor from the `pizza` constructor, rather than setting `this.radius`. For example, `circle.call(this, radius);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting the prototype of the `pizza` class to be an instance of the `circle` class, any instance of `pizza` will automatically inherit from `circle`. As a result the `instanceof` operator will check the constructor of the instance:

```
(new pizza) instanceof pizza; // true
(new circle) instanceof circle; // true
```

and will also walk up the prototype chain to check any other constructors that the instance inherits from too:

```
(new pizza) instanceof circle; // true
(new pizza) instanceof Object; // true
```

Because `circle` doesn't inherit from `pizza` though, you can check that something is a `circle` but not a `pizza` with:

```
(new circle) instanceof pizza; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `instanceof`

```
var p = new pizza();
console.log(p instanceof pizza) //true
console.log(p instanceof circle) //true also
```

Comment: steveukx just posted pretty much the same answer, but better, so ignore this